# regex to search numbers or float numbers in one pattern

Tags: regex

i need a regex to accept both integers or float but not any other characters
like for int ex: 28128 and float with two decimal precision ex: 123123.00 or 123213.05 ...

i have for integers and float [separately] like below

```
var numbers_only = /^[0-9]+$/;
var decimal_only =  /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/;
```

so how can i merge this into one...so i can accept integers and float(2 decimal places)...

Comment: pardon me for any grammatical mistakes..plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an optional group.

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

`(?:\.\d+)?` will match the decimal part if there is any in the input string. `?` after the non-capturing group makes that group as optional.

For two decimal places.

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eV8hK5/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can always merge multiple patterns using `|` (OR) operator:

```
/^([0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$/
```